# How to Reset form Data in Meteor JS?

Tags: meteor

I need to know about to reset form data in meteor.I am using router package.**Whenever clicks submit button then if data saved successfully to reset form and show the same form like save and add another else not saved successfully to show user entered data like no need to reset**.

Here i am using  **Router.go("tempatename")**;.The tempatename is form template.

Use Router.go("tempatename") means renders again same page but not clear the data.Why it's not clear the data i don't know.So please suggest me what to for this or Is there any alternate?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to the same route with Iron Router I think that you are not going anywhere as the route is already loaded! (it does not trigger a page refresh)
But you could do a simple form reset with jQuery after submitting the data:

```
//submit your data
....
//reset the form
$('.my-form').reset();
```

Comment: I am not using form,use only table due to some problems that's why asking to use router package.@Guillaume